# prove of equality of a continuous function, using a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity

Let $f$ a continuous function for all its domain and the sequence:
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{1}=x_{0}, \hspace{0.5cm}a_{n}=f(a_{n-1})
\end{eqnarray*}
for each $n\geq 2$. Show that if the sequence converges to a value $a\in D_{f}$ then $f(a)=a$.

---

My sketch

---

To show that $f(a)=a$ I will show that, for $\varepsilon >0$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 |f(a)-a|< \varepsilon
\end{eqnarray*}
and I know that:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 |f(a)-a|&=&|f(a)-a_{n}+a_{n}-a|\\
&\leq&|f(a)-a_{n}|+|a_{n}-a|\\
&=&|f(a)-f(a_{n})|+|a_{n}-a|
\end{eqnarray*}
For hypotesis I know that sequence converges to $a\in D_{f}$ that is: For all $\varepsilon>0 $, exist $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that, if $n\geq N$:
\begin{eqnarray}
 |a_{n}-a|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
and by other hand, I know that function is continuous in every point in its domain, so, using the convergent sequence and $f$ I have that for all $\varepsilon >0$ and $\delta=\varepsilon$ for all points in the sequence I have that $|a_{n}-a|<\delta$ then:
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(a_{n})-f(a)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Then:
\begin{eqnarray}
 |f(a)-a|&\leq& |f(a)-f(a_{n})|+|a_{n}-a|\\
 &\leq& \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
 &=& \varepsilon
\end{eqnarray}
therefore, like $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, then $f(a)=a$.

---

Is this correct? or I have to consider other way?

Comment: How do you know that you have $|a_n-a|<\delta$ for all points of the sequence?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos By the hypotesis that sequence converges to $a\in D_{f}$ and all points in the sequences are in D_{f}.

Comment: It's almost correct. As @JoséCarlosSantos points out, you probably want to find an $N_2$ such that $n > N_2$ implies $|a_n - a| < \delta$. Then for $n > \max\{N, N_2\}$ you have both that $|a_n - a| < \delta$, which would imply $|f(a_n) - f(a)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and that $|a_n - a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.